# FocalLength to Fov formula in OpenGl

Tags: opengl, graphics, viewport

Im writing a FBX reader and the camera gives me the FocalLength (distance from the camera to the interest).

In opengl I initialize the viewport using Field of View (angle of view).

After some RESEARCH on the web, I seen this formula in an few places:

### **FOV=2.0f*atanf((pixelwidth/2.0f)/focalLength);**

But, the result of this formula gives me a small value. 
PD: I thought it might be radians but converting it from radians to degrees turned out in a too big number.

- for a FocalLength of 35mm, I should get a FOV of 54.432 degrees
- for a FocalLength of 50mm, I should get a FOV of 39.598 degrees
- for a FocalLength of 85mm, I should get a FOV of 23.913 degrees

but the formula doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: ensure you're using same unit for pixelHeight and focalLength (mm)

Comment: this is quite strange, in order to get the scale of the pixelheight, as the focalLength is mm, I used an automatic equation solver and  the scale result differs from one focal length to other. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOV=**ANGLE** * ((float)Math.PI / 180f);

There'is an angle value that is giving the degree, for example if you use 
an camera 35 mm then you need to give the degree 63 in FOV.
So that is **ANGLE** equals with **63**

Here are main angles in angle of the view of the camera:

Super Telephoto 600 mm - 400 mm - > ANGLE=4 or 5 or 6

Telephoto 300 mm - 100 mm  - > ANGLE=8 or 12 or 18 or 24

Medium Telephoto 85 mm- 80 mm  - > ANGLE=28 or 30

Normal 70 mm - ~42 mm ->  - > ANGLE=34 or 46 or 52

Wide angle ~40 mm - 23.2 mm  - > ANGLE=rangle[60..83]

Extreme Wide angle 24 mm - 14 mm -> ANGLE=range[84..114]

Extreme Wide angle if you are under 14 mm then -> ANGLE=range[115..178]

Fisheye ~8 mm -> ANGLE=range[178..179]

CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(FOV, m_AspectRatio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

Shortly That's all.